# Rails nested forms -> different treatment depending on value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

I have this tricky question regarding nested forms. Just say I have the following models:

1. restaurant
2. employees, in which employees belongs_to restaurant.

I also have two types of employees within the employees model,

1. managers
2. staff

The `managers` are designated via `manager` attribute in the `employees` model, it is a `boolean`.

When I go edit the list of employees for each restaurant, it is through a nested form,i.e:

```
<%= f.simple_fields for :employees do |f| %>
  <%= render 'employee_fields', :f => f %>
<% end %>
```

**MY QUESTION**: Is there any way to render different partial forms depending on the type of employee? For example, if the current employee is a manager, then

```
<%= render 'manager_fields', :f => f %>.
```

Otherwise, if the current employee is a staff, then

```
<%= render 'staff_fields', :f => f %>.
```

Comment: In the employee_fields partial you can add if condition. Like if employee.manager then render manager_fields else staff_fields

Comment: My comment was not useful? You needed code for this?

Comment: Then you need architect some other way. Use Rails [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) feature. then you will be storing say in a column `designation`, either `manager` or `staff`. Inside the view call `<%= render f.object.desgination , :f => f %>`.. And you should have `_manager.html.erb` and `staff.html.erb` 2 partials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using *ternary* operator :

```
<%= render f.object.manager? ? 'manager_fields' : 'staff_fields' , :f => f %>
```

If you can change your design, I have a better solution for you. Which follows as :

Use Rails [enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) feature.

Add a field `desgination` as an integer field in your `Employee` model using migration.

Then inside the model:

```
enum designation: [ :staff, :manager ]
```

Then you will be storing say in a column `designation`, either `manager` ( value is 1) or `staff`(value is 0). Now inside the view call `<%= render f.object.desgination , :f => f %>` . And you should have `_manager.html.erb` and `_staff.html.erb` 2 partials.

And you are done!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but that might look a bit ugly:

```
<%= f.simple_fields for :employees do |f| %>
  <%= render (f.object.manager? ? 'manager_fields' : 'staff_fields'), :f => f %>
<% end %>
```

I would probably create a helper method, for example in `ApplicationHelper` or `EmployeesHelper` file:

```
def get_employee_partial(employee)
  employee.manager? ? 'manager_fields' : 'staff_fields'
end
```

and then in form:

```
<%= render get_employee_partial(f.object), :f => f %>
```

Comment: method calling comes with a _cost_, refactor only when you see, you are going to do _duplication_... Otherwise wait.... :)

Comment: @R_O_R : I am sure that there will be a need partials in different places(restaurant's edit page/ employees edit page/ profile page/ etc)  as well. That's why we have partials in the first place, don't we?

Comment: Aha!... I didn't throw any bomb, I re-iterated one line from @sandi.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve conditional rendering by doing something like the following:

```
<%= f.simple_fields for :employees do |f| %>
  <% if f.object.manager? %>
    <%= render 'manager_fields', :f => f %>
  <% elsif f.object.staff? %>
    <%= render 'staff_fields', :f => f %>        
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you only plan on having only `manager` and `staff` roles in your Employee model, then you can simplify the above by using a ternary operator, like in *R_O_R*'s answer.

You may wish to abstract the conditional logic out of your view template. You can do this by creating a helper method, shown in *Surya*'s answer.

Hope that helps!

Comment: yeah, forgot to include the object method on the first write :P

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.simple_fields for :employees do |e| %>
  <% partial_name = e.object.manager? ? 'manager' : 'staff' %>
  <%= render "#{partial_name}_fields" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Dude! you still have one error. one more `?` is needed.. you missed it.. check again. :p